# "object cannot be interpreted as an integer"

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a library with a function that used to return an integer, but will now instead return an object of a "field" class I defined. I wanted this class to behave as close to an integer as possible to maintain compatibility with scripts that use this library, although I couldn't extend `int` since the value needs to be mutable. So I defined `__int__()`, `__add__()`, `__radd__()` and so on, hoping that nobody would even notice that the function no longer returns a regular integer. However, this didn't turn out as I planned, as several built-in functions will now raise "TypeError: 'field' object cannot be interpreted as an integer". (Such as `hex()`.) Is there anything I can do about this, so that my class *can* be "interpreted as an integer"?

To anyone wondering why this change was necessary, the function I mentioned is the `__getitem__()` function of another class ("block") that represents a collection of these "fields". Objects of "block" are used as the `locals` argument for `eval()` to evaluate expressions such as `field1 + field2` and I wanted it to be possible to use other properties of the fields in these expressions.

Comment: Try adding an `__index__(self)` method in your `field` class.

Comment: That works! Thanks, add an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: FWIW, although it may be too late to do so, but according to [PEP 8 - Style Guide for Python Code](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) the convention is to name your classes something that starts with a capital letter. i.e. `Field` and `Block`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Adding an [`__index__(self)`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__index__) method and returning the `int` (or `long`) value contained in your `field` class should make it acceptable to many of Python's built-ins.